# setuptools: Run tests on build dir instead of original dir

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, python-unittest, distribute, python-2to3

I'm currently trying to make a module written for Python2 compatible with Python3.2.

I started by making sure that all code can be automatically converted with `2to3` and added into setup.py:

```
use_2to3 = True,
```

So far, everything is working fine.

**Now, I want to test the converted files.**
The tests are written such that they can run without `2to3`.
My folder structure is:

```
# ls /path/to/mymodule
setup.py
mymodule/
tests/
build/
```

To my setup.py, I added

```
test_suite = "tests",
```

Now I execute

```
rm -rf build/
python3 setup.py build 
python3 setup.py test
```

in order to test my automatically converted code.
But it fails because the test still runs on the `mymodule`directory:

```
File "/path/to/mymodule/mymodule/main.py", line 35
    logger.info(u'Scanning {path}'.format(path=self.path))
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[This Syntax error is in MODULE code, not in TEST code.]
[I expect the path to be: /path/to/mymodule/build/lib/mymodule/main.py]
```

In my `build/` are the correctly converted files.
If distribute is converting them correctly, why aren't the tests also executed for the converted files?

Am I missing something?
I already checked the documentation of setuptools/distribute for a missing parameter.
I don't want to include my tests into the module, as there are several resource files just for testing that would take up unnecessary space.

*=> Can I configure my setup.py to run the tests for a different folder when running in python3?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the line `logger.info(u'Scanning {path}'.format(path=self.path))` is not valid in Python 3.2. The syntax for `u''` isn't valid as the `u` was removed in Python 3.0 and reintroduced in Python 3.3, not 3.2.

This means you should convert your tests to work in Python 3.2 without such Unicode string literals. One alternative is to use bytes literals and decode them (`b''.decode('UTF-8')`) or you could simply use strings as they're already Unicode in 3.x+.

Secondly, I'd recommend using `tox` for testing your codebase in multiple Python versions. It'll use the provided `setup.py` file, create several virtual environments and tests the codebase in each Python version separately. This means you can run your tests in 2.x and 3.x and verify that everything still works.

The `2to3` is not the recommended approach anyway - Python 2.x projects should be ported by adapting the codebase to be compatible with 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Hi, "But it fails because the test still runs on the mymodule-directory". This is no test code but module code.
The 2to3 converted code is okay, but the tests are not executed with this code.

Comment: Anyways, I'll have a look on tox. My first approach was to kepp the changes as minimal but as integrated as possible in order to respect the original author ;)

Comment: @Nippey: the `2to3` is not the recommended approach anyway - Python 2.x projects should be ported by adapting the codebase to be compatible with 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: It is much easier with Python 3.3+... At least the `u''` is useable again. So bad setuptools provides the `2to3` option at all. It is way too inviting to use it. I would like to accept your answer regarding 'adapt the codebase' and 'use tox'. Maybe you want to expand it ^^

Comment: @Nippey: I don't think it makes sense to repeat documentation from elsewhere but yes, `tox` and a 2.x / 3.x compatible codebase are indeed recommended approaches.

Comment: Sry, I just meant to move your comment to the answer, to have a better 'base' to accept. Nevermind ^.^ Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @Nippey: ah sorry, I have now updated my answer with that information too.